# Iterate Images through Folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, iterator, python-imageio

i have a folder of gray-scale images from 0 to 9 and they are around 2400, i need to load them in python so as to have all Zeors together as an array , then Ones together as an array, etc...
i used below code to load one image as an array but i don`t know how to load all images and group each number together.
i thought about iteration through the folder.

Do anyone know how to do it or is there any other idea?

```
import imageio

im = imageio.imread('Train/1.jpg')
```

Comment: Please provide more information on your folder structure. Are all images in one folder containing only images?

Comment: Yes except one txt file

Comment: And how do the files zero, one, zwo etc. differ from each other? How can we determine in which group a given file belongs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following manner:

```
import imageio
for i in range(9):
    im = imageio.imread('Train/'+str(i)+'.jpg')
```

You can also create a 3D variable whose third dimension is equal to the number of files to read the complete data in a single 3D array.